# remove part of a plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to find a way to hide part of a line in a matplotlib plot. Say I have a line with x values from 0 to 100 and I want to hide a portion of the line form x = 20 to x = 30. Is there any efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: plot the parts 0-20 and 30-100 separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mask part of the array, then matplotlib doesn't plot it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.cos(x/10.)

pl.figure()
pl.subplot(121)
pl.plot(x, y)

# Mask part of array
y2 = np.ma.masked_where(((x>20)&(x<30)), y) 

pl.subplot(122)
pl.plot(x, y2)
```

[image]