# How to remove an off-central part of an annulus plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have solved Laplace's equation on an annulus with a central hole. (The blue-red colourmap part on the plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD6mz.jpg. I would like to discard part of this plot (anything outside the black circle I've drawn onto the plot), and I want the `black x` I drew to be the centre of a new, smaller disk, with an off-centre hole in it that used to be a central hole in a bigger disk.

just to be clear, I want to get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNwxG.jpg and I also wonder if it would be possible to save the values of this cropped disk in another array somehow?:

This is the closest thing to what I need that I have found so far: [remove part of a plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177329/remove-part-of-a-plot-in-matplotlib) 
however, I don't know how to implement it in my case. I feel like I should define a new mesh grid somehow, but I'm not sure how to tell it to have an off-centre hole in the plot, moreover, this does not help with saving the values of the smaller disk with the off-central hole into a new array.

This is my code for plotting the original annulus:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initial conditions
Nr = 50
N_phi = 50
radius = 10
r2 = 2
T1 = 35
T2 = 4


# define for plot
r = np.linspace(r2, radius, Nr)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N_phi)
R, phi = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X = R*np.cos(phi)
Y = R*np.sin(phi)


#initialise matrix
T = np.ones((Nr, N_phi))
#print(np.shape(T))

#add solution to laplace's equation to matrix T
for i in reversed(range(0,Nr)):
    T[:,i] = T1 + ((T2-        T1)/np.log(r2/radius))*np.log(r[i]/radius)

#plot
plt.figure()
yes = plt.contourf(X,Y,T,cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar(yes)
plt.show()
```

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first start, a possibility would be to add

```
T = np.ma.array(T) # mask a circle in the middle:
outside = np.sqrt((X + 3)**2 + (Y - 3)**2) > 5
T[outside] = np.ma.masked
```

right before `plt.figure()`, according to https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-demo-py

But I think this looks nicer if the base contourf plot is prepared with higher resolution in `X` and `Y`...

PS: e.g. setting

```
#initial conditions
Nr = 500
N_phi = 500
```

made it look quite sharp

Comment: thanks! I think this'll work the way I want it, it's actually not necessary to replot the unmasked thing only, as I can retrieve the values I need this way anyway.